# Copy the string with `\n` use document.execCommand("copy")

Tags: javascript

I can copy a text use bellow function, create a dummy node, and remove it after copied:

```js
 function copyToClipboard(text){
        var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
        document.body.appendChild(dummy);
        dummy.setAttribute('value', text);
        dummy.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.body.removeChild(dummy);
    }
    copyToClipboard('Hello, World! \nJames')
```

but I find a issue, it can not copy the string with `\n`. how to solve this issue?

Comment: Make your mind up. Which code do you have a problem with. Don't put both in. And what error are you getting?

Comment: @musefan I mean use the `dummy.setAttribute('value', text);` I did not copy success.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense... you are asking 2 different questions in 1. You need to pick the correct question and remove the one you don't want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` element contains a single line value *by design*. If you would like to have a value containing new lines - use `textarea` instead.

Comment: check my eidt-1.

Comment: @sof-03 Try to set value with `dummy.value = text;`

Comment: @hsz: This answer doesn't solve the problem... you should edit it to correct it